# letsencrypt with nginx - renew failed

Tags: cron, nginx, certificates, letsencrypt

since one month i receive an error from letsencrypt renewal cronjob.

- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 Xenial
- letsencrypt version: certbot 0.23.0
- Cronjob command:

  ```
  @daily letsencrypt renew >> /cronjobs/cert/daily-renew.log && /etc/init.d/nginx reload
  ```

Error message:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for website.domain.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Attempting to renew cert (website.domain.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/website.domain.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. website.domain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching https://website.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/UBDM3DZfY837o9OR9E9uMlNKhNbqiN_EdTvXTD9VkDw: Connection refused. Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.domain.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
```

I tried to renew it manually and checked if some updates are available. Also a lot of hours of researching and testing to resolve the problem are behind me. So i tried the last step to create a forum post for it.

Anyone have an idea how to solve the error and renew my certificate?

Comment: Yes, it is a little bit off-topic. But don't know where it is better to ask.
I know this two links. I had take a look to this and made a big research (at most on the pages of letsencrypt community). But no one of the solutions helped me.

Port 80 and 443 are open. 

But i don't will create a new login on letsencrypt if i can ask in this great community - and i hope it is ok on this place.

Comment: @devKyrios https://community.letsencrypt.org/

Comment: ok, i had created one.
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/letsencrypt-with-nginx-renew-failed/93310

Comment: This question is about running third-party applications (`letsencrypt` and `nginx`) on Ubuntu, and as such it’s perfectly [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).